# Why do decorators not work with built in functions?

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators, built-in

I am learning how to use decorators in Python, and I have a solid understanding of it, but I have one question - why can I not use decorators for a built-in function?

Why does this work:

```py
def decorator1(func):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        print("<>=========================<>")
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        print("<>=========================<>")
    return inner

@decorator1
def greet():
    print("Hello!")


greet()
```

and not this?:

```py
def decorator1(func):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        print("<>=========================<>")
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        print("<>=========================<>")
    return inner

@decorator1
print("Hello!")
```

Is it because the print function is executed on the spot, and the `greet()` function is only defined and is only ran after the `@decorator1`?

Comment: Because decorators decorate a function, not a function call

Comment: Decorators work fine with built-in functions. Something else is wrong.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It does not work for me; I use Python 3.7.1 on Mac OS Mojave...

Comment: I didn't say *your approach* works. :-) Just that decorators work on built-in functions, once you know how to apply them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The syntax for `@decorator` can only be used together with a [`def ...` function definition](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions) or [`class ...` class definition](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#class-definitions) statement. That doesn't mean you can't 'decorate' built-in functions.

However, you tried to apply the syntax to an [*expression* statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#expression-statements), one that [*calls*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls) the `print()` function. At most you'd decorate the return value (which for the `print()` function is always `None`).

Decorators are just [syntactic sugar](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-decorator), however. The syntax

```
@decorator_expression
def functionname(...): ...
```

is executed as

```
def functionname(...): ...

functionname = decorator_expression(functionname)
```

but without `functionname` being assigned to twice.

So to decorate `print`, call the decorator explicitly:

```
decorated_print = decorator1(print)
decorated_print("Hello!")
```

Note: I explicitly picked a *different* name here to assign the result of the decorator function to. You *can* use `print = decorator1(print)` too if you really want to. But then you may want to run `del print` later on to unmask the built-in function, or use [`builtins.print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html) to access the original again.

Demo:

```
>>> def decorator1(func):
...     def inner(*args, **kwargs):
...         print("<>=========================<>")
...         func(*args, **kwargs)
...         print("<>=========================<>")
...     return inner
...
>>> decorated_print = decorator1(print)
>>> decorated_print("Hello!")
<>=========================<>
Hello!
<>=========================<>
```